# How do I iterate on a Map object returned from JsonSlurper.parse(JSONFile)?

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, soapui, jsonslurper

I'm using a Groovy script in Ready!Api 1.9.0 to decode a base64 string which is returned in a SOAP response and store the resulting JSON object in a json file. Then take that resulting file and parse it with JsonSlurper to get a Map object.

This object needs to be iterated over so I can find a key and assert its value. I am unable to figure out why the keys aren't found. If I directly call a key using map.get(key) I get an error "No such property". If I directly call it using map.get('key') it returns null. I've also tried `Map.each{k -> log.info("${k}")}` which returns 'interface.java.util.Map' and not the expected list of keys.

```
//create file path
def respFile = "C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Temp\\response.json"

    //set originaldata in response to var
    def response1 = context.expand( '${Method#Response#declare namespace ns4=\'com/service/path/v4\'; declare namespace ns1=\'com/other/service/path/v4\'; //ns1:RequestResponse[1]/ns1:GetAsset[1]/ns1:Asset[1]/ns4:DR[1]/ns4:Sources[1]/ns4:Source[1]/ns4:OriginalData[1]}' )

    //decode the data
    byte[] decoded = response1.decodeBase64()

    //create file using file path above if it doesnt exist
    def rf = new File(respFile)

    //write data to file NOTE will overwrite existing data
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(respFile);
    f.write(decoded);
    f.close();

//begin second file
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
    def inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Temp\\response.json")
    def parResp = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputFile)

    //test to find key
    Map.each{k -> log.info("${k}")}
```

..
    //sample of the json before parse, not the full json though:

```
{
 "Response": {
 "ecn": 1000386213,
 "header": {
 "msgRefNum": "bbb-ls-123" 
},
 "success": true,
 "duplicatedit": false,
 "subjectReturnCode": 1,
 "subject": [
 {
 "uu": 11264448,
 "name": {
 "name3": "WINSTON BABBLE",
 "dob": "19700422",
 "gender": "2",
 "ecCoded": "160824",
 "ecCodeSegment": "ZZ" 
},
 "acc": [
 {
 "ftp": "01",
 "Number": "AEBPJ3977L",
 "issued": "20010101",
 "mMode": "R" 
} ],
 "telephone": [
 {
 "telephoneType": "01",
 "telephoneNumber": "9952277966",
 "mMode": "R" 
} ],
 "address": [
 {
 "line1": "M\/O HEALTH AND FAMILY WELFARE",
 "sCode": "07",
 "cCode": 110009,
 "ac": "04",
 "reportedd": "160430",
 "mMode": "R",
 "mb": "lakjsdf blorb" 
},
```

Comment: can you share a sample of the json?

Comment: @Raphael I've modified the original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question title is very clear, so let's answer that.

Given file `x.json` with content `{"foo":42,"bar":true}`, the following snippet reads the file and prints all key-value pairs:

```
def map = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File('x.json'))
map.each { key, value ->
  println "$key : $value"
}
```

Result (interesting tidbit: the keys are reordered, but it should not matter):

```
bar : true
foo : 42
```

Now the body of your question is quite confusing. All the beginning looks irrelevant, so I'm not sure the snippet above will help, but I hope it will.

Now about your strange result with `interface java.util.Map`:

`Map.each { println it }` yields `interface java.util.Map`, this is perfectly normal, you are "iterating" on the object `Map.class`, not your map object resulting from reading the json file.

Another way to illustrate this:

```
Map.each { println it }
Integer.each { println it }
123.each { println it }
"HI!".each { println it }
```

Result:

```
interface java.util.Map
class java.lang.Integer
123
H
I
!
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Hugues Moreau, that solved my problem entirely. I figured it was a newbie mistake.