# Count items in a JSON object using Groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy

**My JSON file**

```
{
    "General": [
        {
            "AppUrl": "abc.com/",
            "HTTPResponseCode": "200",
            "QA Build Version#": "4.3.44"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the count elements(key-value pairs)  of the above JSON object.

I tried with the below code but it returns a `count` as 1.

**My code**

```
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File(fileName))
def count = InputJSON.General.size()
```

Comment: But there _is_ only one item in your `General` array. The array contains a single object with properties `AppUrl`, `HTTPResponseCode` and `QA Build Version#`.

Comment: @Ivar Yes, you are correct, but I want to get the properties count inside the General Object.

Comment: Okay, but what if there is a second item in the array? Do you want to count just those of the first item? Also what do you attempt to do with this count? (Maybe we can provide a better solution altogether if we know the context.)

Comment: @Ivar i want to parse all the properties inside the General object and based on the count creating a loop  get the key-value pair.instead of getting one by one. in feature it may increase the properties so that i reterive the count and looping with the size.

Comment: @Ivar i want to parse all the properties inside the General object and based on the count creating a loop  get the key-value pair.instead of getting one by one. in feature it may increase the properties so that i reterive the count and looping with the size.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43824582) be a solution for you? Iterate over the items in `InputJSON.General` and then iterate over all the properties. So `InputJSON.General.each { row -> row.each { key, value -> println "$key : $value" } }`

Comment: @Ivar Thanks it's helpful.

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite this question to your actual problem. Getting
the count was for a `for` limit? Or rather what relevance does it have
for the later iterating?  Otherwise it's `data.General*.size().sum()`
for the total of all top level properties or `data.General*.size()` for
a list.

Comment: you want min, max or average count of items in each element?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File(fileName))
def count = InputJSON.General.size()
```

Should be:

```
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File(fileName))
def count = InputJSON.General.keySet().size()
```